# Webview not loading a specific URL

Tags: android, android-webview

[image]`
public class WebActivity extends BaseActivity implements PusherManager.PusherEventListener {

```
private ToolbarView toolbarView;
private WebView webview;
private ProgressDialog dialog;

private boolean isBRIePAYTransaction;
private String link, title, strHtmlData;
private boolean isUnlinked = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

    initData();
    inflateToolbar();

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // Set the java
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(false);

    webview.clearHistory(); // Clearing history and cache of _webview
    webview.clearFormData(); // Clears the data in _webview
    webview.clearCache(true); // Clears cache in _webview
    webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(link)) {
        webview.loadUrl(link);
    } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(strHtmlData)) {
        //this will be used when html text is passed in the intent instead of link
        webview.loadData(strHtmlData, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
    }

    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(WebActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());
}

private void initData() {
    title = getIntent().getStringExtra(IntentParam.WebView.TITLE);
    link = getIntent().getStringExtra(IntentParam.WebView.LINK);
    strHtmlData = getIntent().getStringExtra(IntentParam.WebView.HTML_DATA);
    isBRIePAYTransaction = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(IntentParam.WebView.IS_BRI_ePAY_TRANSACTION, false);
    if (isBRIePAYTransaction) {
        PusherManager.getInstance().register(this);

        findViewById(R.id.ctv_do_not_press_back).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.rl_parent_done_toolbar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        CustomTextView tvDone = (CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.done_web_activity);
        tvDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}

private void inflateToolbar() {

    toolbarView = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_view_web_activity);

    toolbarView.setToolbarTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.settings_title));


    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
        toolbarView.setToolbarTitle(getString(R.string.loader_loading));
    } else {
        toolbarView.setToolbarTitle(title);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    // drawer
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onPusherEvent(String eventName, String data) {
    if (eventName.equals(PusherManager.EVENT_TRANSACTION)) {
        RechargeResponse rechargeResponse = (new Gson()).fromJson(data, RechargeResponse.class);

        Intent briEPAYRechargeResponse = new Intent();
        briEPAYRechargeResponse.putExtra(IntentParam.WebView.BRI_ePAY_RECHARGE_RESPONSE, rechargeResponse);
        setResult(IntentParam.RequestCode.CREATE_BRI_EPAY_TRANSACTION, briEPAYRechargeResponse);
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (isBRIePAYTransaction)
        PusherManager.getInstance().unRegister(this);

    super.onDestroy();
}

private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        handleUrlResponceFromLinkaja(url);

        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            view.reload();
            return true;
        } else if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
            MailTo mt = MailTo.parse(url);
            Intent i = newEmailIntent(mt.getTo(), mt.getSubject(), mt.getBody(), mt.getCc());
            startActivity(i);
            view.reload();
            return true;
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(view.getTitle())) {
                toolbarView.setToolbarTitle(view.getTitle());
            }
        }

        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
        super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        // ignore ssl error
        if (handler != null) {
            handler.proceed();
        } else {
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, null, error);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
}

private void handleUrlResponceFromLinkaja(String url) {

    if (url.contains("src=linkaja") && url.contains("mandateID=")) {
        showProgressDialog(null);
    } else if (url.contains("source=linkaja") && url.contains("success=true")) {
        if (url.contains("action=delink")) {
            isUnlinked = true;
        }
        PreferenceManager.setOnceUserLinkedLinkaja(true);
        UserApiManager.getInstance().fetchUserData();
        dismissProgressDialog();
        closeWebview();
    } else if (url.contains("source=linkaja") && url.contains("success=false")) {
        dismissProgressDialog();
        String content;
        if (url.contains("action=delink")) {
            content = getResources().getString(R.string.linkaja_delinking_failed_msg);
        } else {
            content = getResources().getString(R.string.linkaja_linking_failed_msg);
        }
        showErrorMsgDialog(content);
    }

}

private void closeWebview() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(IntentParam.LinkajaFragment.IS_UNLINKED, isUnlinked);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}

private Intent newEmailIntent(String address, String subject, String body, String cc) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{address});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    return intent;
}

private void showErrorMsgDialog(String message) {

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
        final CustomDialogFragment customDialogFragment = CustomDialogFragment.getInstance(StringValues.EMPTY,
                message, getString(R.string.okay), null);
        customDialogFragment.setListeners(new CustomDialogFragment.CustomDialogClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPositiveButtonClicked(String inputText) {
                customDialogFragment.dismiss();
                closeWebview();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNegativeButtonClicked() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {
            }
        });

        customDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), CustomDialogFragment.class.getName());
    } else {
        closeWebview();
    }
}
```

}`i am tring to load url in webview 
[enter link description here](https://sandbox.m.dana.id/m/portal/cashier/checkout?bizNo=20191120111212800110166711700294814&timestamp=1574243577619&originSourcePlatform=IPG&mid=216620000000451758252&sign=EUuaP%2Bv3VB90wR%2ByxacDNBhc9F0YHQdRkpYwToc7pp%2FKSEphzL7Oonlt4bA0DHUeAjKkMCb%2B7FqUR81OUudGuFOHTh8Y84OKh2dW24VqzQf%2Bw6TM8goPHGHjCGGohEgK1OEBvIsG%2FmNbbUYEuNPPiAGoWgyiYqdNRTexr%2FTzJipYG%2FQGzzFcccEBAca5GxRwocyvgQ80P3p7LEsPcbhLKnVOq64L6ZrGW7kdthIUVxzgip4WVDajrb8%2F9fXXQOM%2BVwGHiaAzah03sRqDF%2FwR%2BElY2Hpllfs%2F1UX8TtkFVnQP8ag%2FrL9OXzWryIVRgsLYXLkYkV4lA6l8Hb13Hfbcow%3D%3D)

its loading in the browser . and also loading in the IOS webview.
its not loading in android webview.
I have also implemented the webview SSL error and page load error callback but its not giving any error also

Comment: add some code on how youre handling ssl anroid

Comment: Did you tried enabling JavaScript?

Comment: show some code or error logcat

Comment: android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in your manifest application section, try it

Comment: @NagendraHariKarthick i have enabled the javascript to true

Comment: show the code. You probably did something wrong.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i have added the activity code

Comment: @Umair i have added the code

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
        startWebView("your url");

//Method
      private void startWebView(String url) {



    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        //Show loader on url load
        public void onLoadResource (final WebView view, String url) {

        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        }

    });
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
webview.webViewClient = AppWebViewClient()
```

Client

```
  class AppWebViewClient() : WebViewClient() {

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {

            view.loadUrl(url)
            return true
        }


    override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView, handler: SslErrorHandler, error: SslError) {
        var message = "SSL Certificate error."
        when (error.primaryError) {
            SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED ->
            message = "The certificate authority is not trusted."
            SslError.SSL_EXPIRED ->
            message = "The certificate has expired.";
            SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH ->
            message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
            SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID ->
            message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
        }
        message += "\"SSL Certificate Error\" Do you want to continue anyway?";
        //Log your message
        handler.proceed()

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue as my device os was lower version and the URL that I was trying has the latest HTML5 code which was causing an error.
so I have tried this

> https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have declared network permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code and also your link work perfectly for me
just check this code:

```
final WebView webView=findViewById(R.id.webv);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://sandbox.m.dana.id/d/ipg/inputphone?ipgForwardUrl=%2Fd%2Fportal%2Fcashier%2Fcheckout%3FbizNo%3D20191120111212800110166711700294814%26timestamp%3D1574243577619%26originSourcePlatform%3DIPG%26mid%3D216620000000451758252%26sign%3DEUuaP%252Bv3VB90wR%252ByxacDNBhc9F0YHQdRkpYwToc7pp%252FKSEphzL7Oonlt4bA0DHUeAjKkMCb%252B7FqUR81OUudGuFOHTh8Y84OKh2dW24VqzQf%252Bw6TM8goPHGHjCGGohEgK1OEBvIsG%252FmNbbUYEuNPPiAGoWgyiYqdNRTexr%252FTzJipYG%252FQGzzFcccEBAca5GxRwocyvgQ80P3p7LEsPcbhLKnVOq64L6ZrGW7kdthIUVxzgip4WVDajrb8%252F9fXXQOM%252BVwGHiaAzah03sRqDF%252FwR%252BElY2Hpllfs%252F1UX8TtkFVnQP8ag%252FrL9OXzWryIVRgsLYXLkYkV4lA6l8Hb13Hfbcow%253D%253D");
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

these two line is for scaling webview content 100%(Fit to screen):

```
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Add Permission in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: the same code is not working for me i have added the my activity code and error i am getting

Comment: can you pls check for this link

https://sandbox.m.dana.id/m/portal/cashier/checkout?bizNo=20191120111212800110166711700294814&timestamp=1574243577619&originSourcePlatform=IPG&mid=216620000000451758252&sign=EUuaP%2Bv3VB90wR%2ByxacDNBhc9F0YHQdRkpYwToc7pp%2FKSEphzL7Oonlt4bA0DHUeAjKkMCb%2B7FqUR81OUudGuFOHTh8Y84OKh2dW24VqzQf%2Bw6TM8goPHGHjCGGohEgK1OEBvIsG%2FmNbbUYEuNPPiAGoWgyiYqdNRTexr%2FTzJipYG%2FQGzzFcccEBAca5GxRwocyvgQ80P3p7LEsPcbhLKnVOq64L6ZrGW7kdthIUVxzgip4WVDajrb8%2F9fXXQOM%2BVwGHiaAzah03sRqDF%2FwR%2BElY2Hpllfs%2F1UX8TtkFVnQP8ag%2FrL9OXzWryIVRgsLYXLkYkV4lA6l8Hb13Hfbcow%3D%3D

Comment: it's working perfectly @NitinZagade check my answer i used your link in code

Comment: pls copy exact url in comment.
 the url that is genarated after clicking the first url  is diifrent

Comment: @NitinZagade make one demo project and then copy my code,run and tell me what happened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202798/discussion-between-milan-tejani-and-nitin-zagade).